# How are Ring0 (kernel mode) debuggers implemented?

Tags: debugging, kernel

There doesn't seem to be much info on the net about this topic.

Could someone explain what the general idea behind kernel mode debuggers is,
and how are such tools implemented? From what I have gathered it seems they
implement their own tiny operating system for the debugger exclusively to run
underneath the user OS, but I'm not quite sure.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to implement yet another stealth OS to debug an OS kernel. As long as the kernel that's being debugged is still alive, can execute threads, stop and resume them (on all CPUs, of course, if the system is multiprocessor) and there's a way to communicate with it using a console or a dedicated I/O port, something, that's enough.

Setting breakpoints in kernel threads is usually done in the same way as in user threads. And so is reading and writing memory.

It is convenient to do kernel debugging using an extra PC, where the debugger actually runs. The two PCs can be connected using a serial, 1394, USB or network connection. The debuggee must be configured to listen to debug commands on the debug port and respond appropriately (e.g. stop/restart execution, read/write memory, set/reset a breakpoint, etc etc). The debuggee must have dedicated debugger threads (or something similar to threads) to preempt other existing threads and perform requested debug commands (outlined above).